# Application.Exit followed by Process.Kill best practice

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to terminate a WinForms process from an event handler that runs on a different thread than the UI thread. I want to follow a pattern of asking nicely first, then forcefully killing it if it does not terminate within a set amount of time. Something like:

```
Application.Exit();
Thread.Sleep(GracefulShutdownTimeoutMs);
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

This seems to work fine from my testing. The reasoning being that calling `Application.Exit` causes the message loop to terminate, which in turn causes the thread that called `Application.Exit` to terminate, thus never reaching the `Process.Kill` line.

Is there anything wrong with this approach and is there something better?

Comment: What thread are you doing this on? I hope it's a background thread, otherwise your `Thread.Sleep` will stop your application from gracefully shutting down, surely? Although I'm not sure whether `Application.Exit()` can be safely called from a background thread...

Comment: @canton7: Sorry, it's a winforms app, don't know why I said WPF.

Comment: @canton7: Yes, it is called from an event handler that runs on a different thread.

Comment: Instead of nuking the application tell the main form to exit. Check [Closing form from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309785/closing-form-from-another-thread). To remove coupling, you could use a CancellationTokenSource that calls `Form.Close` when triggered and trigger it from another thread

Comment: This is dramatically thread-unsafe, it fires a bunch of events on the wrong thread.  Like FormClosing, FormClosed, Disposed.  Controls get disposed on the wrong thread as well.  This somehow didn't blow up in your face, but that was just luck.  If this must be done from a worker thread (it certainly doesn't have to) then use Environment.Exit() instead.