# ContinueWith method doesn't run some code but other yes

Tags: vb.net, async-await, task, continuewith

I have a task object that downloads some stuff from the azure blob, in this case an exe. I want to trigger the end of the download to open the .exe automatically. I found that the `ContinueWith` method should work for me.

The problem is that if I do something like below (a simple msgbox) I see the code working well and the msgbox shown when the task is over.

```vb
Dim downloadTask As Task = Task.Run(Function() blobmnger.downloadWithProgress("QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.7-1-Setup-x86_64.exe", "startupResources", utils, up))

downloadTask.ContinueWith(Sub(task)
                              If task.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
                                  MessageBox.Show($"qgis has completed his download here {Path.Join(utils, "QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.7-1-Setup-x86_64.exe")} you can close the window ")
                              End If
                          End Sub)
```

If I change the code with the app doesn't break but doesn't do anything:

```vb
downloadTask.ContinueWith(Sub(task)                                             
                              If task.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
                                  up.close()
                                  process.Start(Path.Join(utils, "QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.7-1-Setup-x86_64.exe")) 
                              End If
                          End Sub)
```

In this case `up` is a form object that represents a progress bar that keeps track of the progress of the download.

Even if I wrap the `Process.start` in a `try` block it doesn't pop any exception.

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith` instead of `async/await`? There's no valid reason unless you're trying to create some really low-level library

Comment: `Even if I wrap the Process.start in a try block it doesn't pop any exception` - because the exception is before Process.Start, at the point where you are trying to [close the form from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18309785/11683).

Comment: `up is a form object that represent a progress bar` you can use the Progress class for this, *and* avoid cross-thread issues. To download in the background you can use `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync`. The progress you want to report is actually the progress of copying the stream contents from the stream returned by `GetStreamAsync` to the local file.